# NameError when trying to run linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am getting an error when I try to run this program :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro-' , animated=True)


def init():
    plt.scatter(xtest, ytest, color='g')
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1.0)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1.0)
    return ln,

def update_frame(frame):
    m , c = mc_values_anim[frame]
    x1, y1 = -0.5, m * -.5 + c
    x2, y2 = 1.5, m * 1.5 + c
    ln.set_data([x1, x2], [y1, y2])
    return ln,


anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update_frame, frames=range(len(mc_values_anim)), 
                                init_func=init, blit=True)
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

the error is :

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-a04b9e0d4368> in <module>
     17 
     18 
---> 19 anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update_frame, frames=range(len(mc_values_anim)), 
     20                                 init_func=init, blit=True)
     21 HTML(anim.to_html5_video())

NameError: name 'mc_values_anim' is not defined
```

please resolve my query

Comment: As the error message says, you have not defined the `mc_values_anim` variable.

Answer (score 0):

create a new cell above and type this:
mc_values_anim = mc_values[0:250:5]